# MyBatis fails to execute IF statement for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

I am trying to be prevent inserting the duplicate data in my table. In order to do that I tried to put the following statement into my MyBatis XML file

```
<insert id="insertResource" parameterType="TopologyResource">

DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM discovery_graph.topology_resources 
   WHERE resourceType = #{type} AND resourceSubType = '#{subType} AND storageTechnology = #{storageTechnology} ABD  name = #{name} AND attributes = #{attributes} AND nativeData = #{nativeData}) = 0
THEN 
    INSERT into discovery_graph.topology_resources (
    id,
    resourceType,
    resourceSubType,
    storageTechnology,
    name,
    attributes,
    nativeData
    )
       values ( #{resourceId,javaType=java.util.UUID,jdbcType=OTHER,typeHandler=UUIDTypeHandler}, #{type}, #{subType}, #{storageTechnology}, #{name}, #{attributes}, #{nativeData}
    )
ELSE 
   RAISE NOTICE 'Edge already exists';
END IF;
END
$do$
```

The same statement executes with no problem via PSQL (with real data instead of the placeholders), but when I try to execute this statement via MyBatis it fails with the error:

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
   ### The error may involve TopologyResourcesMapper.insertResource-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: DO  $do$  BEGIN  IF (SELECT count(*) FROM discovery_graph.topology_resources      WHERE resourceType = ? AND resourceSubType = ? AND storageTechnology = ? ABD  name = ? AND attributes = ? AND nativeData = ?) = 0  THEN       INSERT into discovery_graph.topology_resources (      id,      resourceType,      resourceSubType,      storageTechnology,      name,      attributes,      nativeData      )         values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?      )  ELSE      RAISE NOTICE 'Edge already exists';  END IF;  END  $do$
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; SQL []; The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.] with root cause
```

MyBatis has no problem executing just the INSERT statement, but the IF fails. I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is really an ad hoc *PL/pgSQL* statement, which I suspect is what *MyBatis* is having an issue with it. *psql* is a much thinner wrapper around *libpq* and features some enhanced script-execution features (among other special features, such as `\copy`), so that is probably why it worked OK there.

In general the approach I take with *PL/pgSQL* and *MyBatis* is to define the function as a full-fledged *PL/pgSQL* function directly in the database, and then call it via *MyBatis*.

In this case, you would have the function take as arguments the parameters currently in the *MyBatis* `INSERT` above. Then, you would switch it from `INSERT` to `SELECT` in your *XML*, and call the function with the form `SELECT foo(arg1, arg2)` as the tag content.

That will invoke the function server side, and it will do the 
included `INSERT` using the supplied arguments if the `IF` condition is satisfied.